# How can I use the child selectors here?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-selectors

Please refer to the posted image. I want to add a `margin-left` on the first image and then in the rest of image I don't want them. Can I use the child selectors to achieve this or there is any other way?

Can I make the images, `overflow: scroll` like we do in case of text? As I don't know jquery/javascript as of now.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background:gray;
 
 /*border: 2px solid yellow;*/
}

.wrapper {
 width: 93%;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.headwrap {
 
 padding-top: 70px;
}

.logo {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
}

.socialbuttons {
 float: right;
 
 
}

.socialbuttons ul {
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
 
}

.socialbuttons ul li {
 float: left;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 padding:0;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background: #000;
 border-radius:30px; 
}
.socialbuttons ul li img{
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.navbar {
 margin-top: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #db3636;
 float: left; /* this and see changes */
}

.navbar ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 5px; /* the 0 helps with making the borders span full height of navbar*/
 /* float producing wrong results */
}

.navbar ul li {
 float: left;  /* height of menu bar increases when float is defined */
 display: inline; /* does it have any use ? */
 padding: 25px 10px;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 width: 15%;
}

.navbar ul li:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}


.navbar ul li:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}

.clearfix {
 *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
 line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}

.slider img {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}
.text{
 color:white;
 margin-top:-35%;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 80px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size : 50px;
 line-height: .5;
}

#project {
 background-color: #555653;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.head {
 float: left;
 background-color: #1D1D1C;
 width: 100%;
}

.head h3 {
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial , sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.imgContainer img {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 40px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Industrial Website demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<link href="damion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="headwrap">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Damion max">
   </div>
   <div class="socialbuttons">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="facebook.png"></img></li>
     <li><img src="twitter.png"></img> </li>
     <li><img src="feed.png"></img></li>
     <li><img src="google.png"></img></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="clearfix">
     <li style="width:5%;"><img src="home.png"></li>
     <li>ABOUT US</li>
     <li>GALLERY</li>
     <li>EVENTS</li>
     <li>BLOG</li>
     <li>CONTACTS</li>
     <li style="padding:0; width:20%;"><input type="text" style="background:black; height:30px; width:90%;  margin:20px 0 0 20px; border:0;  border-radius:10px;"></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="slider">
   <img src="industrial.jpg" />
  <div class="text">WE ARE PROFESSIONAL,<p><span style="font-weight:lighter; line-height:100%; color: yellow ;">COMPETITIVE AND COMPETENT</span></p></P></div>
  </div>
  <div id="project">
   <div class="head">
    <h3>FEATURED PROJECTS</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
    <img src="4.jpg"/>
    <img src="5.jpg"/>
    <!--<img src="6.jpg"/>-->
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  

























 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: i want to make it like this]

Comment: selector:first-child {styles..} you can use this

Comment: yes :) thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:first-child` selector for this:

```
.imgContainer img:first-child{
       margin-left:10px;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: i have one more query. there is no chat option here :/

Comment: your are free to ask

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using this css

```
.imageContainer img:first-child 
 { 
   margin-left:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first child with any of the given selectors below:

```
.imgContainer img:first-of-type
.imgContainer img:first-child
.imgContainer img:nth-child(1)
```

If you want to set some sort of overflow to your images, you'll need to wrap them in another element, like a generic `div` and set your overflow rules to this element, standard overflow rules won't apply directly to `img` elements.
See [CSS Tricks - overflow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)